# How to use COUNTIFS in Google Sheets between dates & less than

Tags: google-sheets

Having problems getting the correct value when using `COUNTIFS` between two dates, and less than value.

I need to find the less than the value in cell C8:I8, based on the dates in Cell C6:I6. 
Start date is C2 and end date is L5 (which is the date today)

```
=COUNTIFS(C8:I8, "<600", C6:I6, ">=C2", C6:I6, "<=L5")
```

I expect to get `1` as a result, due to one incident being below 600 between 11/02/19 (C6) & 13/02/19 (L5), but it shows up as `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTIFS(C8:I8, "<600", C6:I6, ">="&C2, C6:I6, "<="&L5)
```

[image: 2]